# Powershell Test for Excel Password Protection

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a script that I am using to convert and password protect a number of Excel documents.  The older documents are in Excel 2003 format and I can convert/password protect them fine.  As I get to more recent documents, the files are in Excel 2010 format and thus only need to be password protected.  I am trying to find a way to check if an xlsx file is already password protected and can therefore be skipped (likely to be a 2003 file that was already processed).  If I open the file as it has a password, then excel will pop-up and ask for that password before continuing even though I have the visible property set to false.  I need a way to automate the check because there are a lot of documents to go through.  This is the code I have so far:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param (
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$Path,
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][switch]$Visible,
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][string]$ToFolder,
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][string]$Password,
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][switch]$Force
)
begin {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
    $xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
    Write-Verbose 'Opening Excel COM object.'
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
    if ($Visible -eq $true) {
      $Excel.visible = $true
    } else {
      $Excel.visible = $false
      $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
      $Excel.ScreenUpdating = $false
      $Excel.UserControl = $false
      $Excel.Interactive = $false
    }
    $filetype = "*xls"
} process {
    if (Test-Path -Path $Path) {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include '*.xls' -recurse | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Verbose "Processing $($_.Basename)"
            if ($ToFolder -ne '') {
                $FilePath = Join-Path $ToFolder $_.BaseName
                $FilePath += ".xlsx"
            } else {
                $FilePath = ($_.fullname).substring(0, ($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
                $FilePath += ".xlsx"
            }
            if (!(Test-Path $FilePath) -Or $Force) {
              Write-Verbose "Opening $($_.Basename)"
              $WorkBook = $Excel.workbooks.open($_.fullname)
              Write-Verbose "Saving $($_.Basename) to $FilePath with password $Password"
              $WorkBook.saveas($FilePath, $xlFixedFormat, $Password)
              Write-Verbose "Closing $($_.Basename)"
              $WorkBook.close()
            } else {
              Write-Verbose "$($_.Basename) already converted."
            }
        }
    } else {
        return 'No path provided or access has been denied.'
    }
} end {
    Write-Verbose 'Closing Excel'
    $Excel.Quit()
    $Excel = $null
    [gc]::collect()
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
```

Comment: It's the `$Excel.workbooks.open` call that stops and asks for a password?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Yes, that's where it stops.

Comment: Ok, just throwing out ideas here. What happens if you pass in a dummy password to `open`? Will it still prompt or throw an exception?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: It throws an exception.  So I guess I could attempt to open it with an invalid password and then catch the exception.

Comment: I can't see any other obvious way to check using the API, however I'm not exactly an expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies that I forgot to come and update this.  For anyone looking in the future what I ended up doing is opening the file as a datastream and checking the file signature (first 4 bytes of the file).  Standard 2010 Office documents (.xlsx, .docx, etc.) are really Zip files and have the standard zip file signature.  This Powershell code gives me a byte array with that sig:

```
$sig = [Byte[]] (0x50,0x4b,0x03,0x04)
```

Encrypted Office documents on the other hand have the standard file signature common to all Office docs for like the last 5 versions.  So, this code snippet shows how I read the sig from each document to check and then test if it is unencrypted (has the sig above):

```
$bytes = get-content $_.fullname -encoding byte -total 4
if (@(compare-object $sig $bytes -sync 0).length -eq 0) {
  # process unencrypted file
}
```

majkinetor's answer above would work as well though.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: TBH, my solution would also allow you to actually enter the password before procedding :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use another script that will execute conversion inside a job. If Excel prompts the conversion script will block until prompt is gone. You could wait for job for some time (like 10s) and if it doesn't return kill it.

If you start several jobs at once in parallel (assuming this is possible with Excel), the script will always convert some of the files wile waiting for others.

---

Serial solution could also use Autohotkey script that waits for the Excel prompt. When prompt shows you can kill the excel which will return control to the powershell script (you can ignore any error that rises this way) which can then continue iteration. AHK script would have only few lines such as:

**`ExcelMonitor.ahk`**

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2   # see [1]
Loop {
    WinWaitActive, <Set Excel Prompt Window Title Here>
    Run, taskkill /IM excel.exe /f
}
```

**Explanation**:

Inside the forever loop, script waits for Excel to show and then kills it and continues to wait for another prompt. This will return the control to your posh script.

Run this ahk script before your powershell script and close it when conversion is done. You could also arange your powershell script to start the ahk script before conversion and close it afterwards.

[1] : https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm#Parameters

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  The problem with this is that I have thousands of spreadsheets to go through and even with running it in parallel it would take forever if I had to wait on a timeout for each file.  Also, opening a document with password protection from script will open the Excel window and prompt for the password even with the visible option false.  Thus, I would get a bunch of screens constantly popping up.  I guess I could use a VM but again, less than ideal.  I think that catching the exception on a bad password will probably work better.

Comment: See my edited post. It will kill excel as soon prompt appears. Honestly, it doesn't matter much how long it takes if its a 1 run operation; you can run it overnight or something.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add precision, the answer provided works only for 2007+ files.
To achieve this for 97-2003 files you can try this :

```
# Look for 97-2003 files
If ($excelSheet.Extension.Length -eq 4)
{
    # Get Excel sheet file header
    $header = Get-Content $excelSheet.FullName -Encoding Unicode -Total 1

    # Check if Excel file is password protected
    If (($header -ne $null) -and ($header -notmatch "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider"))
    {
        Write-Host = "Excel sheet : $excelSheet is unencrypted."
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "Excel sheet : $excelSheet is password protected !"
    }
}
```